# How to write sql query for this task

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have tables: user (one to many reviews/tours), tour (one to many reviews), review (many to one tour| many to one user), usertour (with columns user_id, tour_id). So. I want to get all tours for user with review for tour and if review for tour does not exist tour should present anyway. Help me pls to write sql query for this.

I wrote this but it returns wrong result:

[image: look result here]

```
select * 
from tour tr 
     join usertour ut on tr.id = ut.tour_id 
     left join review r on tr.id = r.tour_id 
where ut.user_id = 80
```

Comment: sorry. i add result image now

Comment: Are you trying to get reviews from all users? or just the specified users' reviews for the tours they were on?

Comment: no. i need tours for specific user and reviews for these tours. but if review null should present in results

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself.

```
select * from tour tr join usertour ut on tr.id = ut.tour_id
left join review r on tr.id = r.tour_id
where ut.user_id = 100 and (r.user_id = 100 or r.user_id is null)
```